# Cleaning up a rotating image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have created a nice little image gallery for the web. I set out wanting 3 things. 1. The whole gallery had a basic level responsiveness to it. 2. The gallery would take images of any size, and display them without cropping. 3. The gallery would run automatically. If you look [here(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/eL0vaL44/1/) I have done just that. The automatic slide show is just a small bit of jQuery.

```
setInterval(function () {
  $(".image_background").last().animate({
        left: '-=1000'
        }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
          var top_element= $(this).detach();
          top_element.css({"left": 0});
          $(".image_gallery").prepend(top_element);
    })}, 2000);
```

I am quite happy with it. It's the css bit that I am not so sure about.

```
.main_image_gallery{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 30%;
  left: 3%;
  background-color: #4e9ba1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image_background{
  background-color: #4e9ba1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.gallery_image{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

For reference, here's the HTML

```
<div class="main_image_gallery image_gallery">
    <div class="image_background">
      <img class="gallery_image" src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" ></img>
    </div>
    <div class="image_background">
      <img class="gallery_image" src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo.gif" ></img>
    </div>
    <div class="image_background">
      <img class="gallery_image" src="http://th09.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2011/290/8/e/batman_logo_circleless_by_machsabre-d4d6s56.png" ></img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I feel like there is a simpler way to do it. Any thoughts on how I can clean it up, maybe improve the responsive aspects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the css part, I started from the updated fiddle @cimmanon provided. I basically agree with all the things he added. I also went ahead and turned your markup into a `ul` as he (or she) correctly suggested. I would like to provide my own insights as well:

- You are closing your `img` tags, however they can never contain any content so the closing tags are redundant (and perhaps even invalid). You can either make them self-closing (`<img ... />`) or just omit them in html5.
- You are using a lot of different classes in your markup. There is no real need for that; all it does is make your code longer and harder to read. I would go for selectors like `.image-gallery img` instead of `.gallery_image`. I admit that in theory this is slightly less performant, but I doubt you'll be able to see, or even measure, the difference. And it makes your markup a lot easier to maintain (less code when adding slides, and less chance of making typos in all those class names).
- I would definitely not animate the `left` property, but go for a `transform: translate3d` in stead. It is a lot better for performance as explained [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).
- I would use css transitions, instead of the jQuery `animate`. It is again better for performance, and it I believe it makes your code a lot better structured. If you decide to change anything in your animation, you just have to update your css and you don't have to start digging into your javascript. I'm a big fan of only using Javascript for thing that can't be done through css.

I went ahead and applied my suggestions to the fiddle, which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/eL0vaL44/3/

Comment: Self-closing the img tag is just optional in HTML5, not invalid.

Comment: yeah but it future proofs the markup to be polyglot markup

Comment: @cimmanon, to be clear, I was referring to the `</img>` tag. I looked it up (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element) and the spec clearly says `Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.`

Comment: Any chance you know a better way to position the gallery, other than with padding in 'before'?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup looks pretty good.  You're using just enough elements to get the desired effect and no more.  Semantically speaking, a list might be more appropriate here and would give you the same structure.

It's unclear why your .main_image_gallery element is absolutely positioned.  If it's because you want to keep the child elements contained within, you should be using `position: relative` instead.  If it's so you can have the container sized relative to the parent element (in this case, the body element), there's a different technique you can use:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio

```
.main_image_gallery{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #4e9ba1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.main_image_gallery:before {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   padding-bottom: 150%;
}
.image_background{
  background-color: #4e9ba1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eL0vaL44/2/

You don't need to specify `display: inline-block` if you're absolute positioning an element.  Absolutely positioning an element will cause it to shrink to its contents.

Comment: The method you got from stackoverflow, forces the hight to be much taller than I would like. It makes the gallery taller than it is wide.

Comment: I chose an arbitrary value:  with a padding of 150%, the height will always be 50% taller than it is wide.  If you want it smaller, just reduce it to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: But reducing the padding, will reduce the position height.